# Building AOSP in Docker: too many open files

Tags: docker, ubuntu, android-source

How do I resolve the `too many open files` error in my docker container?

I'm attempting to create a Ubuntu 20.04 container for my AOSP build (vendor mods to our AOSP limit it to 20.04...) in Docker Desktop (v2.25.2) on a 22.04 machine.  128 GiB of RAM, 2TiB free.

The container itself is pretty simple.  I'm binding the workspace, but when I run a build I constantly hit `too many open files`

I'm seen many posts here about running purges dangling images/volumes first, raising the ulimit, *etc*, nothing seems to help.  The only thing that seemed to have an impact is when I raised the Virtual Disk Limit, but even raising that to 800GiB only got me out of `lunch` and into the very start of the build.

I'm creating the container with:

```
  docker create \
    -it \
    --privileged \
    --ulimit 'nofile=1000000' \
    --name "aosp" \
    --mount type=bind,source=/my/host/workspace,destination=/aosp/workspace \
    --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/tmp \
    aosp:latest
```

(Not shown is a mount for a ccache dir, and private files like `.netrc`, `.git-credentials`, *etc*)

The `--ulimit` option seems to have no impact.

The issue doesn't seem to be the number of file descriptions:

```
(container)
# sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 1840       0       6635196
```

In fact nothing seems to be limited:

```
(container)
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 259210
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 82000
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

As for resources, in Docker Desktop I set:

- CPUs: 40
- Memory Limit: 64 GiB
- Swap: 3 GiB
- Virtual Disk Limit: 776 GiB

I'm not imposing any limits that I know of:

```
(host)
❯ dkCin -f "{{.HostConfig.Ulimits}}" aosp
[nofile=1000000:1000000]
```

My host filesystem:

```
(host)
❯ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1             259:0    0   3.7T  0 disk  
...
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0   3.7T  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 253:0    0   3.7T  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-swap 253:1    0  11.4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─vgubuntu-root 253:2    0   3.7T  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                               /
❯ df
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                       13G  2.8M   13G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  3.7T  2.0T  1.6T  57% /

❯ mount
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: When I load the entire ~130GiB workspace into a volume, my build gets a lot further, I'm actually able to build some modules after fixing the python symlinks.  So this seems to be an issue with bind mounts.  That said having the workspace in a volume isn't that convenient for syncing or flashing.

Comment: Is this real Docker-on-Linux, or is there an additional non-Linux host OS on top? I would be deeply unsurprised to see a VM (being used as the Docker host) have its filesystem virtualization layer be subject to ulimits itself.

Comment: It's Linux all the way down.  About "but a problem with the filesystem that's serving that bind mount from the host end", are you suggesting that maybe I should create a btrfs (or something) on the host and bind from there?  Or maybe I could cut the number of CPUs but AOSP builds already take hours

Comment: Eh. If there's no VM in the way and Docker Desktop on Linux is just operating in the same "namespaces in the host kernel" way that regular pure OSS Docker does (and _not_ the way Docker Desktop works on, say, MacOS), then the above theory doesn't hold up.

Comment: That said, to satisfy my curiosity, what _is_ the filesystem that's being plumbed through? btrfs should be fine (and Docker is capable of making good use of it directly); if it were a network filesystem or anything FUSE-based, that would still get some side-eye.

Comment: Which storage layer does `docker info` report as in use? If your host is using btrfs, you want a btrfs-aware storage layer rather than the generic overlay2

Comment: Good question, this machine was provisioned by my work.  I'd have assumed ext4, but I think it's an encrypted drive in an lvm: (the comment formatting will destroy this, so I'll append it in the question text)

Comment: It reports: "`Storage Driver: overlay2`"

Comment: If it's block-layer encryption that won't cause any problems with respect to file descriptor limits; it's only userspace filesystem-level encryption (encfs, gocryptfs, etc) that I'd be extremely worried about.

Comment: overlay2 is default, and widely used, but it's not ideal for anything where you're going to be operating on a huge number of files (or, particularly, on extremely large directories). I couldn't say with certainty that it's at cause here (it's easier to speak with confidence about the performance characteristics than correctness impact), but there _is_ a lot more going on in terms of moving parts than you'd have with [the btrfs docker storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/).

Comment: I'm happy to give it a try.  But I'm confused (and new to mounts), I thought I only chose a driver when creating volumes, I didn't think I had the option with a bind mount

Comment: A bind mount is just making something that's already available be exposed somewhere else -- it uses the same driver as the source. There's not a separate "bind mount" driver -- a bind mount is an operation on the VFS tree itself, mapping a new set of paths to a preexisting instance of a preexisting driver.

Comment: That is all to say, to use btrfs here you _do_ need to have a block device (though it _can_ be a loopback device if need be, thus potentially representing space on an ext4 or other preexisting filesystem) that the actual btrfs driver can be pointed at (on your host).

Comment: I've never created a loopback block device before.  I see some instructions at https://linuxhandbook.com/create-virtual-block-device/  Are you suggestion that I might use `losetup` to create a loopback to my host path, use `mfks.btrfs` or something to format it, mount it somewhere, and then bind that into my container?  Would I be able to contact you somehow for help tomorrow if I get stuck on this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256079/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the exact issue, following @charles-duffy advice in the comments/chat led me to switch [Docker to using the BTRFS storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/) (which [isn't supported by Docker Desktop for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-storage-drivers-per-linux-distribution)).  I speculate that the cause is the combination of my local setup + docker + how resource intense the AOSP build is.

This solved my problem in my AOSP build, and when I applied it to another container that also has a large build system, it sped it up considerably (I don't have good stats yet, but some component builds had a 5x speedup)

To set this up, I followed [this page to create virtual block devices](https://linuxhandbook.com/create-virtual-block-device/) using `losetup` (but used `mkfs.btrfs` to format).  I created a ~400GiB device for AOSP, and a ~100GiB one for docker.

I mounted `/var/lib/docker/` on the docker device (as in the [instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/#configure-docker-to-use-the-btrfs-storage-driver)), changed my `storage-driver` to `btrfs` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, restarted docker, and mounted my AOSP workspace to the other device. *i.e.*

```bash
mount /dev/loop16 /var/lib/docker
systemctrl restart docker

mount /dev/loop14 /mnt/aosp
docker create ... --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/aosp,destination=/aosp/workspace aosp:latest
```

The issue vanished.

(My builds didn't work immediately, because `repo` is flaky sometimes I deleted the workspace and complately re-synced, but then the build was able to complete)